# json - how to correctly add ArrayList<String> items to ArrayList<CustomObject>

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a json like this

```
{
"News": [
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "963426",
            "gallery": [
                {
                    "image_path": "/images/metbuat/images_d/963426_0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_path": "/images/metbuat/images_d/963426_1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_path": "/images/metbuat/images_d/963426_2.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "959846",
            "gallery": [
                {
                    "image_path": "/images/metbuat/images_d/959846_0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_path": "/images/metbuat/images_d/959846_1.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

when parsing this json and getting data from it I faced problem. It adds all gallery images for every news item. But other values like 'watched', 'body' is adding correct

```
private ArrayList<FeedNewsItem> feedNewsItemArrayList;

JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("News");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() - 1; i++)
{
  JSONObject newsItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject data = newsItem.getJSONObject("data");

  imageUrl = "https://metbuat.az" + data.getString("image_t");
  titleText = data.getString("title");
  subTitleText = data.getString("sub_title");
  watched = data.getString("views_stats");
  body = data.getString("details_full");

  if (!data.getString("gallery").equals("false"))
  {
   JSONArray galleryJsonArray = data.getJSONArray("gallery");

   // I think problem is here. This block adding all news images to every single news item
   for (int j = 0; j < galleryJsonArray.length(); j++)
   {
     JSONObject imageJsonObject = galleryJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
     imageURL = "https://metbuat.az" + imageJsonObject.getString("image_path");

     galleryImagesList.add(imageURL);
   }
 }

 // adding every news details to list one by one
    feedNewsItemArrayList.add(new FeedNewsItem(imageUrl, titleText, subTitleText, time,date, watched, body, addDateTimestamp, currentDate, galleryImagesList));
}
...
Intent newsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
FeedNewsItem clickedItem = feedNewsItemArrayList.get(position);
newsIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_GALLERYLIST, clickedItem.getmGalleryArrayList());
```

So when opening specific news everything is OK, but gallery images for all news appearing in single news item

This is code for gallery images in NewsActivity.java class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
galleryImagesList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_GALLERYLIST);
private void getGalleryImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < galleryImagesList.size(); i++)
    {
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(NewsActivity.this);
        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        imageView.requestLayout();

        Picasso.get().load(galleryImagesList.get(i)).into(imageView);
        horizontalScrollLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

In this image I need to get only this images in red box. Instead I'm getting all images for all news with gallery property in json

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfIrc.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add below dependency into app level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

then after make some pojo class like below ..

```
public class GalleryItem{

@SerializedName("image_path")
private String imagePath;

public void setImagePath(String imagePath){
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getImagePath(){
    return imagePath;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "GalleryItem{" + 
        "image_path = '" + imagePath + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
```

}

```
public class NewsItem{

@SerializedName("data")
private Data data;

public void setData(Data data){
    this.data = data;
}

public Data getData(){
    return data;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "NewsItem{" + 
        "data = '" + data + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
```

}

```
public class Response{

@SerializedName("News")
private List<NewsItem> news;

public void setNews(List<NewsItem> news){
    this.news = news;
}

public List<NewsItem> getNews(){
    return news;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "Response{" + 
        "news = '" + news + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
 }
```

then after call like below in activity.

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream ims = assetManager.open("file.txt");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);

    GsonParse gsonObj = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
}
}catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: you used volley for web service calling.